# Canvas.toBlob polyfill not working with createObjectURL in Chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas

My app requires the manipulation and temporary storage of many large images.  In order to manage this efficiently we are using blob URL references to all images.

However, following manipulations we obviously need to create a new Blob URL for the new client side generated image, taken from a canvas.

Firefox has support for native `Canvas.toBlob()` which works perfectly, we then create a new blob url reference from this blob like so:

```
 var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
 var bloburl = url.createObjectURL(blob);
```

For all ther browsers we are using the following polyfill:

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

This works for on IE and Opera but fails on Chrome where the following javascript error message is returned:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: blob:http%3A//www.exampledomain.com/d4693a94-ebf9-4608-b721-1cee1a04fd00
```

When I `console.log()` the bloburl variable I get the following:

In Firefox/IE/Opera:

```
blob:d4693a94-ebf9-4608-b721-1cee1a04fd00
```

In Chrome:

```
blob:http%3A//www.exampledomain.com/d4693a94-ebf9-4608-b721-1cee1a04fd00
```

It appears something is going wrong in the creation of this URL reference but I have no idea how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.